# Ping a IP's contenidas en un archivo en C

Tags: ip

Estoy intentando lanzar ping a distintas IP's que tengo contenidas en un archivo .txt (variable x) y de momento me lanza sólo a partir de la segunda, por algún motivo la primera no me la lee (consecuentemente, si la segunda ofrece respuesta, me lo printa también como dicta la orden siguiente). Me estoy rompiendo la cabeza para entender cómo rebobinar, ya que no sé implementar rewind/fseek en una concatenación como la que uso, y no comprendo cómo no lee desde la primera línea del .txt.

Gracias de antemano, esto es lo que tengo de momento:

```
{
    FILE* fp, * fp2;
    char ch[500], x[500], str[500], line[BUFSIZ];
    char term[20] = "Media"; // Línea de caracteres de búsqueda para remarcar IP's que respondan positivamente
    char ping_cmd[256];

    printf("\n    Escribe la ruta del documento deseado\n\n");
    scanf("%s", x);

    fp = fopen(x, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n    El archivo no se ha podido encontrar\n\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    // Bloque que printa el contenido del archivo donde están las IP's
    while (fgets(ch, sizeof(ch), fp))
    {
        printf("%s", ch);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    // Bloque que analizará las IP's que responden positivamente
    sprintf(ping_cmd, "ping %s", ch);
    FILE* f = _popen(ping_cmd, "r");
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, f))
        if (strstr(line, term))
            printf("\n\n   The IP responds: %s", ch);
        else("\n\n   The IP %s does not respond", ch);
    _pclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Podrias dar un ejemplo del archivo. Por otro lado cuando decis que te lanza a partir de la segunda, como llegas a esa conclusión?

Comment: Porque abro el archivo "out.txt" al que redirecciono los resultados y sólo veo reflejado el ping de la segunda IP..., el archivo sigue la estructura tipo:
192.168.1.1(salto de línea)128.1.1.1

Comment: No sabía..., sin embargo, con la modificación que me citas, sigue guardándome sólo ping a la segunda línea, no sé cómo hacer para que el puntero empiece por el principio (y, una vez sea capaz de leer a partir del principio, trabajar en alguna iteración tipo for... para leer el archivo de entrada completo).

Comment: Borré el comentario. Porque entendí algo diferente.

Comment: Edité mi código para enfocarlo de manera distinta, pero sorprendentemente pasa por alto la primera IP también. Modifico el archivo .txt y lo mismo...

Comment: Cuando leeas el .txt mete las líneas en un arreglo para después recorrer ese arreglo .
Creo que puedes intentar zanitizar las variables y proteger mejor las ips